# How to assign html content to ngbPopover and popoverTitle when it is part of a nested element?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a nested component that uses `ngbPopover` and `popoverTitle`. The content that will be displayed will be given through `@Input()` properties.

**The problem:**
If the given input is like `"<b>Some Title</b>"`, I would like to have that be bold rather than displayed literally.

I tried using  as described in the docs [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples), but in my case, whatever I bind will have the markup. My markup isn't predefined. So that didn't help.

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "help-popup",
    template: `<span 
      class="fa fa-question-circle-o btn-outline-info btn-sm"
      style="font-size: 18px" triggers="focus:blur"
      [placement]="placement"
      [ngbPopover]="helpText"
      container="body"
      [popoverTitle]="helpTitle"></span>`
})

export class HelpPopupComponent {
    @Input() placement: string = "top";
    @Input() helpText: string = "";
    @Input() helpTitle: string = "";
}
```

I want to use it like:

```
<help-popup helpTitle="<b>Bold Title</b>"
              helpText="<u>Underline text</u>"></help-popup>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ng-bootstrap Popover component allows HTML in its content but, as far as I can see in [the documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api), not in its title: the `ngbPopover` property can be a template, the `popoverTitle` property is just a string.

[**This plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GKHoYfxZFpy6eKgTXesM?p=preview), adapted from the ng-bootstrap documentation, shows how to display `helpText` as HTML content in the popover. In the popover template, the value of `helpText` is assigned directly to the `innerHTML` property of a div element to avoid the [HTML escaping](https://lishman.io/angular-2-interpolation) that would occur with interpolation:

```
<ng-template #popContent><div [innerHTML]="helpText"></div></ng-template>
```

and the template is bound to the `ngbPopover` property of the element:

```
<button ... [popoverTitle]="helpTitle" [ngbPopover]="popContent">
  ...
</button>
```

Comment: ahhh the innerHtml! Thank-you!