# ngbPopover with html returned from a function

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

I have an `ngbPopover` which makes a call to return the html I want to populate it with. I have read from the docs (click [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples)) that I need to use a template, and if I put html in this it's fine, but I want a function to return the html, but this just comes out as a string.

```
<ng-template #popContent>{{getConnBreakdown(opp)}}</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="top" [ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="Connection Types">{{ getTotalConnections(opp) }}</button>
```

and the function looks like:

```
getConnBreakdown(opp: IOpportunity){
  let returntable = '<table><tbody>';
  this.connectonTypes.map(t => 
    returntable +=  '<tr><td>' + t.name + '<td><td>' + opp.products.filter(p => p.connectionTypeId === t.id).reduce((a, b) => { return a + b.quantity; }, 0) + '</td></tr>'
  );
  returntable += '</tbody></table>';
  return returntable;
}
```

I've tried binding to `innerHTML`

```
<ng-template #popContent ng-bind-html="getConnBreakdown(opp)"></ng-template>
```

but I always just get the html as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` inside a `<div>` that in located in your templates, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947027/3623608). Modify your `<ng-template>` like this:

```
<ng-template #popContent>
    <div [innerHTML]="getConnBreakdown(opp)"></div>
</ng-template>
```

Here is a [running stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scsgep-f5w6vi?file=src/app/popover-basic.html) that I modified and got this result (*I also adjusted the placement to properly show it for this example*):

[image: Stackblitz result]

Good luck!

Comment: you absolute legend. Cheers